# Couldn´t match expected type error in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I´m trying to implement a function that saves the highest score of a player in a game through a txt file. This is the code:

```
import System.IO
import System.Directory

saveHighScore:: Int -> IO()
saveHighScore num = do
  let stringNum = "" ++ show num
  let file = "score.txt"
  writeFile file stringNum

readHighScore:: IO() -> Int
readHighScore = do 
  content <- openFile "score.txt" ReadMode
  score <- hGetContents content
  let highScore = read score :: Int
  return highScore
```

But the code is giving this error and I don´t know what to do:

```
localStorage.hs:17:9: error:
* Couldn't match expected type: IO () -> Int
              with actual type: IO Int
* In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    content <- openFile "score.txt" ReadMode
  In the expression:
    do content <- openFile "score.txt" ReadMode
       score <- hGetContents content
       let highScore = ...
       return highScore
  In an equation for `readHighScore':
      readHighScore
        = do content <- openFile "score.txt" ReadMode
             score <- hGetContents content
             let highScore = ...
             ....
 |
17|         content <- openFile "score.txt" ReadMode
 |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. You claim your function has type `IO () -> Int`, but it's impossible for any interesting function to have this type. The only possible implementation is a constant function that ignores the `IO ()` and produces the same result regardless of its input.

The right type is the one the compiler is suggesting, `IO Int`.

Comment: `but it's impossible for any (total) function to have this type` - this clearly isn't true, eg `const 0` is such a function and is perfectly total. I suspect for total you meant "non-trivial".

Comment: @RobinZigmond You're quite right. "Total" was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71185918/126014), *amalloy* gives the explanation.

To fix the issue, the easiest step is to remove the type declaration:

```
readHighScore = do 
  content <- openFile "score.txt" ReadMode
  score <- hGetContents content
  let highScore = read score :: Int
  return highScore
```

Then load the file in GHCi and query GHCi about the type:

```
> :t readHighScore
readHighScore :: IO Int
```

That's the type. You can add it back as a type declaration:

```
readHighScore :: IO Int
readHighScore = do 
  content <- openFile "score.txt" ReadMode
  score <- hGetContents content
  let highScore = read score :: Int
  return highScore
```

There are lots of tools and add-ons that can do this in your IDE of choice, but GHCi works everywhere, I should think.